# Stop swinging on your chair

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

If someone is  "rocking" his or her chair, will it be natural to use:

> Hey! Stop **swinging** on your chair!

Is the use of "swing" natural in this context? It is a normal chair.

The person leans back and moves it (chair) sideways on two legs..

Comment: Both verbs can refer to a "pendulum-like" motion, and both occur ([here's "swinging"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Stop+swinging+on+your+chair%22) and [here's "rocking"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Stop+rocking+on+your+chair%22)). With ***swinging***, the "fulcrum" is normally above the moving object (monkey gripping an overhead branch), but with ***rocking*** it's normally below (person sitting in a rocking chair). People usually say things like _Don't **lean back** on the chair [like that]_ when someone tilts a chair back so the front two legs are off the ground.

Comment: Can you describe the type of chair and the movement in more detail? For example, it's a rocking chair and the person is moving back and forth... or it's a normal chair, and the person is leaning back so that the chair is on the back two legs... or it's a swivel chair, and the person is moving his upper body from left to right... or a chair on casters...

Comment: It is a normal chair @JavaLatte.

Comment: So what do you think @FumbleFingers ?

Comment: I think what I said in the first comment. 9 times out of 10 it would be entirely arbitrary whether to use ***swinging*** or ***rocking*** (or some more precise phrasing, such as ***leaning on the back legs of the chair***, which is what people often do, even though it risks damaging the chair). There's also the possibility of *Stop **playing / fidgeting** in / with your chair.* But do you at least understand the *potential* (not *inevitable*) difference between swinging and rocking as shown by my examples?

Comment: No, swinging on your chair would only make sense if the chair was a swing.  Rocking is as acceptable a way to say this as tilting, or leaning back.  Perhaps there is a difference here between American and British English.

Answer (score 1):

Swinging is a very unusual way to describe this, as FumbleFingers noted in comments. To strictly answer your question, no, it would not be a natural use.

However, if you are trying to emphasize a particularly exaggerated motion or energetic person, and you had the context to support it, you could use swinging in a figurative way as an exaggeration.